# Can't find any way to blur shape after draw in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I draw some Shape with openGL command in CCNode. And now I want deal Gaussian Blur with it.
But I can't find any way to do this.
Anybody recommend?

.

.major of solve code:

```
    CCRenderTexture *renderTex = [[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:480 height: 320] retain];
    renderTex.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    [renderTex begin];
    //here can put any draw code with opengl
    [curve visit];
    [renderTex end];
    CCTexture2DMutable *mutableTexture=[[[CCTexture2DMutable alloc]
                                        initWithImage:[renderTex getUIImageFromBuffer]]autorelease];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [mutableTexture contentSizeInPixels].width, [mutableTexture contentSizeInPixels].height);
    [AWTextureFilter blur:mutableTexture radius:8 rect:rect];
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:mutableTexture rect:rect];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFrame:frame name:@"1"];
    CCSprite *blur = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
    [blur setPosition:ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2)];
    blur.opacity=200;
    [self addChild:blur];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to:

- render the whole scene to the render target (to the texture), you can use Framebuffer Objects
- then you draw a fullscreen quad with that previuous texture (with the scene) attached.
- in the end you can perform gussian blur effect (or some other postprocessing effect)

some info:

- http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/tutorial-masking-sprites-in-cocos2d-with-ccrendertexture/
- http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html
- http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/

Comment: I am a newier of opengl. And I don't want fullscreen get blur. Just some simbols. Have some easy way ?

Comment: you can blur texture that covers the object... (using shaders for instance), but to blur shape's edges you have to use some 'global' solution which is postprocessing (and render to texture)

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html and http://pastebin.com/kqcJAaLf  Is it useful? I can't understand.

Comment: fen. Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: I draw it use those code: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 
 glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, len);
 
 // restore default state
 glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Comment: I gave you enough examples... maybe this effect is simply to hard for you at the moment. Try to improve you knowledge in OpenGL/ES

Comment: here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6315/page/2 tell me how to convert opengl shape to ccsprite. And then easy to operate.